# Shell script: Removing leading and trailing spaces between fields in a pipe delimited file

Tags: shell

I have a pipe delimited file as below

```
1  |Mike    |   2000|     2|
2  |Peter   |   4000|     2|
```

.....
...
.... and so on.

I want to remove the leading and trailing spaces between fields. It should look like as below

```
1|Mike|2000|2|
2|Peter|4000|2|
```

Is there any way in shell script to achieve this output?

Thanks,
Chandraa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
cat datafile | tr -d ' \t'

cat datafile | tr -d '[:space:]' # will remove all spaces including the new line at the end of each line
```

Comment: Useless use of cat. `tr` can take the filename as argument.

Comment: Not all versions of `tr` can take filename as argument (eg mine can't). Using `cat` is more portable.

Comment: It is true that `tr` is not required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) to take filename as argument. But that is no reason to invoke useless use of cat. Input redirection is the right way to do this that does not involve useless use of cat. That is precisely the purpose of input redirection. For example, `tr -d ' \t' < foo` is completely portable too. If you had argued that `cat` here is just a placeholder for another pipeline, then it would have made sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cat datafile | sed -e 's/[ \t]*|[ \t]*/|/g'
```

Comment: it is not useless, cat here is being used as a 'mock'. normally the sed part will be fed data from some other pipe, using cat instead of the full program simplifies it imho.

Comment: This is the solution that I was looking for. The regex other languages use is a little different than what is being used by sed in UNIX.